# udev rule is not working for usb disable on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: udev

Below udev rule is not working on ubuntu 20.04  though working on 16.04 and 18 version of ubuntu

disable ports

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/disable-usb-rules.sh"
```

disable-usb-rules.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
for host in $(ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product|awk -F '/' '{print$6}'|grep -v usb); do echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/$host/authorized;done
```

Comment: Below rule is also not working to disable usb storage on ubuntu 20.04
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'for host in $(ls /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage); do echo $host > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage/unbin

Comment: Any idea why these rules are not working?

Comment: Does `LC_ALL=C journalctl -u systemd-udevd` give any error messages?

Comment: Maybe you get some idea from [my question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1373624/21005)